# Triggering email as soon as users register to Mobile App

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk

I have a mobile application and currently, we have the data flowing from the app to the data warehouse, and then loading through Marketing Cloud FTP to SFMC.

I'm new to integrating with Mobile, and was wondering if the MobileSDK would be able to expose that data directly to Marketing Cloud?

I'd like to trigger Welcome emails or push notifications this way, as opposed to waiting for the Data Warehouse feed to come through to trigger an event.

Some problems we are facing with going the data warehouse route:

- Constant data model changes- this breaks my import automations
- Lag time from mobile data flowing to data warehouse to marketing cloud
- Not able to achieve real-time action

Answer (score 0):

Yes the SDK lets you set the contactkey and provided data during the registration process. Reference the GitHub for more detail, [iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html) & [Android](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html)

> You can configure the SDK in a mode that delays registration until a contact key is set by the application. Use this configuration mode only in implementations where the device running your app is tied to a specific contact key in Marketing Cloud and not to a generic device contact.
>
> You can use attributes to segment your audience and personalize your messages. Before you can use attributes, create them in your MobilePush account. Attributes may only be set or cleared by the SDK. See the Reserved Words section for a list of attribute keys that can’t be modified by the SDK or your application.
>
> You can use tags to segment your audience. Tags are commonly used to allow customers to express their interests. For example, a news app offers predefined article categories, such as sports, headlines, and entertainment. App users select the categories, or tags, that they want to receive notifications for.

Then you can setup filters and automations and journeys to engage with subscribers on this data